# Regular Expression IsMatch() method in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I compiled the code:

```
namespace TestRegExp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(args[1], args[0]))
                Console.WriteLine("Input matches regular expression.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Input DOES NOT match regular expression.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run:

- `TestRegExp.exe ^a\d{5}$ a12345` shows `Input matches regular expression.`
- `TestRegExp.exe ^a\d{5}$ aa12345` shows `Input matches regular expression.`
- `TestRegExp.exe ^^a\d{5}$ a12345` shows `Input matches regular expression.`
- `TestRegExp.exe ^^a\d{5}$ aa12345` shows `Input DOES NOT match regular expression.`

Why the second option shows `Input matches regular expression.`?

The '^' symbol represents the string init... alright? and why do I have to repeat this?

Comment: What CLI did you use? It sounds like command line interpretation problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the regular expression itself.

If you print `args[0]` to the console, you'll see that it doesn't contain the `^`. This is because Windows parses it as an escape character if the expression is not quoted.

If you call it like this:

```
TestRegExp.exe "^a\d{5}$" aa12345
```

You'll get the expected result.

Comment: Can you clarify why the `^` is not included?

Answer (score 8):

The `^` is used as an escape character in the Windows commandline environment. It tells the command interpreter to treat the next as a literal character (since some characters like `<`, `>` and `|` have special meanings otherwise).

`^a` evaluates to `a` when parsed.

`^^` evaluates to `^` when parsed.